Why the :after psuedo element is not on same line with the div?
I am trying to align the ::after pseudo element on the same line of the div. But why the ::after element is little down from the start position of div?



*,*::after{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box; 
}
.bar{
    height: 8px;
    width: 60px;
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid blueviolet;
}
.bar::after{
    content: '';
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: calc(100% + 1px);
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    border: 1px solid blueviolet;
    background-color: rgba(50, 67, 255);
}
<div class="bar"></div>




Related? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17115344/absolute-positioning-ignoring-padding-of-parent

Or - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14706866/css-borders-interfering-with-absolute-positioning



*,*::after{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box; 
}
.bar{
    height: 8px;
    width: 60px;
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid blueviolet;
}
.bar::after{
    content: '';
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    left: calc(100% + 1px);
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    border: 1px solid blueviolet;
    background-color: rgba(50, 67, 255);
}
<div class="bar"></div>




Thanks. But I want to understand why top: 0 is not working?

Because top refers to the padding edge of the parent, borders are outside of the padding

You can replace border with outline it will works. As @Paulie said top don't include border but padding
