# Adding a rounded similar to border-radius to outline

Tags: javascript, html, css

Using CSS3 I would like to know if there is any way to `create a rounded effect` to an `outline` property.

Maybe a CSS Hack or a JS option possible whitout using jQuery.
The effect I would like to achive is similar looks like

```
border-radius: 10px;
```

this is my code

```
.focus {
    outline:whitesmoke solid 3px; 
}
```

I would need for webkit.

EDIT:
After some research  and how suggested, such property is not implemented in webkit.

Comment: To what element are you applying this `.focus`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5394116/outline-radius

Comment: There seems to be a `-moz-outline-radius` for mozilla only, check https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/CSS/-moz-outline-radius

Comment: Why use `outline` instead of `border`?

Comment: I am using .focus on a simple div

Comment: Adrenaxus thanks for your comment do you know one for web kit?

Comment: @GibboK doesnt exist for webkit