# How to change the border of an element when selected?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a query and have tried to do some research but i am having trouble even trying to google what i am looking for and how to word it. Currently each div has a label and then an input field. i have made all these input fields with rounded edges. my problem is when i click in the chosen area a rectangular border appears around the edge. the image can be viewed here: `http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=6128132`

how can i change the appearance of this border?

This is is my css code:

```
    div input{
     border: 2px solid #a1a1a1;
        padding: 10px 40px; 
        background: #dddddd;
        width: 300px;
        border-radius: 25px;
    }
```

This is part of my html:

```
<div class="fourth">
        <label> Confirm Password: </label>
        <input type="text" name="cPassword" class="iBox"  id="cPassword" onkeyup="passwordValidation()" placeholder="confirm it!" autocomplete="off">
        <p id="combination"></p>
    </div>
```

Comment: It is not a border but an outline, so you can style it using the `outline` property. But you are not saying *how* it should be changed. Removing it, changing its color etc. easy. Setting rounded corners is not, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5394116/outline-radius

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela thanks. is it easy to set round corners as a different colour when selected?all the jsfiddles in the answers to the questions above do not seem to have borders that change colours once clicked

Comment: @RagingBull - updated the example to do that: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28148449/404335

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution is to remove default outline on focus using:

```
div input:focus{
    outline: none;
}
```

```css
   div input {
     border: 2px solid #a1a1a1;
     padding: 10px 40px;
     background: #dddddd;
     width: 300px;
     border-radius: 25px;
   }
   div input:focus {
     outline: none;
   }
```

```html
<div class="fourth">
  <label>Confirm Password:</label>
  <input type="text" name="cPassword" class="iBox" id="cPassword" onkeyup="passwordValidation()" placeholder="confirm it!" autocomplete="off" />
  <p id="combination"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: @AlexChar I also have not voted down, but your code snippet will not work, Im running in Firefox 35.0

Comment: This answer assumes that “change” means “remove” in the question. Removing an outline is guaranteed to cause usability and accessibility problems.

Comment: @Teemu removed it but i prefer to close `input` in any case.

Comment: @AlexChar Ah you may be right actually. Just read the question again.

Comment: I've not downvoted this, but this won't work in most modern browsers. This is because these days the input:focus is set using a box-shadow rather than an outline.
To make this work, add this:  
  
div input:focus {  
  outline: none;  
  box-shadow: none !important;  
}  

And, yes, you need the !important

Answer (score 2):

This is the `outline` property and can be set in the same way as a `border`, it is typically assigned for the `:focus` state of suitable elements, it can also be set to `none`

[**More on `outline` from MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline)

> The CSS outline property is a shorthand property for setting one or
>   more of the individual outline properties outline-style, outline-width
>   and outline-color in a single declaration. In most cases the use of
>   this shortcut is preferable and more convenient.

[**More on `:focus` from MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus)

> The `:focus` CSS pseudo-class is applied when a element has received
>   focus, either from the user selecting it with the use of a keyboard or
>   by activating with the mouse (e.g. a form input).

It is also interesting to note that by adding the `tabindex` attribute to elements (such as `div`) you can also enable styling of the `:focus` state.

```css
 div input {
   border: 2px solid #a1a1a1;
   padding: 10px 40px;
   background: #dddddd;
   width: 300px;
   border-radius: 25px;
 }
 input:focus {
   outline: none;
   border-color:red;
 }
```

```html
<div class="fourth">
  <label>Confirm Password:</label>
  <input type="text" name="cPassword" class="iBox" id="cPassword" onkeyup="passwordValidation()" placeholder="confirm it!" autocomplete="off" />
  <p id="combination"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: this is great, thanks. would vote up but not enough rep im afraid.

Answer (score 2):

It is not a border but an outline, so you can style it using the `outline` property. But things depend on *how* it should be changed. Removing it, changing its color is etc. easy; but setting rounded corners is not (you can only fake it), see [Outline radius?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5394116/outline-radius)

Simply removing the outline is bad for usability and accessibility, since the outline, “focus rectangle”, shows the user where the focus us. You might consider compensating for this by using some other way of indicating the focus. One simple possibility is to change the border color or style or both. So when focused, the element does not get an outline but its border changes so that it resembles the focus rectangle. The following illustrates the techniques and makes the focus rather apparent; tune to fit your overall design:

```css
  div input{
     border: 2px solid #a1a1a1;
        padding: 10px 40px; 
        background: #dddddd;
        width: 300px;
        border-radius: 25px;
     }
  div input:focus {
        outline: none;
        border-color: red;
        background: #ffd;
     }
```

```html
<div class="fourth">
        <label for="cPassword"> Confirm Password: </label>
        <input type="text" name="cPassword" class="iBox"  id="cPassword" onkeyup="passwordValidation()" placeholder="confirm it!" autocomplete="off">
        <p id="combination"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: this is great, thanks. would vote up but not enough rep im afraid.