# Why won't my border round off it's corners?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make to simple buttons. Easy. However they will not for some reason round off the corners of the outline. This is what i have for my HTML and CSS

```
<a class="login-worker" href="">LOG IN AS A WORKER</a>
<a class="login-user" href="">LOG IN AS A USER</a>

.login-worker,
.login-user {
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: 600;
    outline: 3px solid #000000;
    margin: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
    padding: 20px;
    padding-right:75px;
    padding-left:75px;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #248FD4;
```

}

Comment: What browser are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The cause seems to be `outline: 3px solid #000000;`

Change to:

```
border: 3px solid #000000;
border-radius: 5px;
```

After all, your question states `Why won't my **border** round off it's corners?`
But if it's outline you need then please see [Outline radius?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5394116/outline-radius) (user289112 provided link but removed his answer)

Answer (score 0):

Use `border: solid 2px #000;` not outline.

[Example here](https://jsfiddle.net/kdgah5hw/)

```
.login-worker,
.login-user {
    display: block;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: 600;
    border: solid 2px #000;
    margin: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
    padding: 20px;
    padding-right:75px;
    padding-left:75px;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #248FD4;
}
```