# Remove the glitch when number gets circled (Preferably CSS)

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-transitions

I am generating a table of numbers as can be seen in the snippet that follows. The problem I am facing is that when a number (or cell) is clicked, it gets the class `black`, followed by `circle` and then `number` repeatedly.

When the class `circle` is active; the column with that particular number gets **widened slightly** by `2px`. This happens because of the extra `2px` received from the `border` property of the said class.

*Can this somehow be resolved?* I would really like the values to be in relative context , for eg. `%`s, `em`s etc. and not `px` or `pt`.

```js
Classes = ['number', 'black', 'circle'];
$('.td').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $span = $(this).children('span');
  var state = $span.data('state');
  $span.removeClass(Classes[state]);
  state = ++state % 3;
  console.log(state);
  $span.data('state', state).addClass(Classes[state]);
});
```

```css
* {
  font-size: 1em;
}
#game {
  display: table;
}
.tr {
  display: table-row;
}
.td {
  display: table-cell;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: .5em;
  border: 1px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
.number,
.black,
.circle {
  padding: .5em;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: center;
  transition: ease 1s;
}
.black {
  color: white;
  background-color: rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.8);
}
.circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='game'>
  <div class='tr'>
    <div class='td'><span class='number' data-state='0'>4</span>
    </div>
    <div class='td'><span class='number' data-state='0'>5</span>
    </div>
    <div class='td'><span class='number' data-state='0'>1</span>
    </div>
    <div class='td'><span class='number' data-state='0'>2</span>
    </div>
    <div class='td'><span class='number' data-state='0'>4</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='tr'>
    <div class='td'><span class='number' data-state='0'>5</span>
    </div>
    <div class='td'><span class='number' data-state='0'>4</span>
    </div>
    <div class='td'><span class='number' data-state='0'>3</span>
    </div>
    <div class='td'><span class='number' data-state='0'>2</span>
    </div>
    <div class='td'><span class='number' data-state='0'>1</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='tr'>
    <div class='td'><span class='number' data-state='0'>3</span>
    </div>
    <div class='td'><span class='number' data-state='0'>3</span>
    </div>
    <div class='td'><span class='number' data-state='0'>2</span>
    </div>
    <div class='td'><span class='number' data-state='0'>1</span>
    </div>
    <div class='td'><span class='number' data-state='0'>4</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='tr'>
    <div class='td'><span class='number' data-state='0'>1</span>
    </div>
    <div class='td'><span class='number' data-state='0'>4</span>
    </div>
    <div class='td'><span class='number' data-state='0'>5</span>
    </div>
    <div class='td'><span class='number' data-state='0'>3</span>
    </div>
    <div class='td'><span class='number' data-state='0'>2</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='tr'>
    <div class='td'><span class='number' data-state='0'>5</span>
    </div>
    <div class='td'><span class='number' data-state='0'>1</span>
    </div>
    <div class='td'><span class='number' data-state='0'>2</span>
    </div>
    <div class='td'><span class='number' data-state='0'>4</span>
    </div>
    <div class='td'><span class='number' data-state='0'>4</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As an aside, I'd also like a solution (if possible) to the following:

1. When `black` state, the parent `div` on the whole should get the black background.
2. The circle (as well as the black background of `black` class) touches the boundaries of the cell it is inside. Can this be dealt with?

Comment: According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6810937/1016716), the solution is to use `box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px black;` instead of the border; I'm not sure if that makes this question a duplicate though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The change in width and height is because you are adding a `border` of 1px width when circle class is added. This is not present initially and hence affects the size. To fix it you can add a transparent 1px border as default for the element.

Coming to the other two questions, setting `display: inline-block` for the `span` element and doing away with the padding on the `td` element would get the background color apply to the element in full. The padding on parent would always mean there is a space between it and child content. This space will not get colored when we apply the `background` to the child div.

**Note:** I have increased the padding on the child element from `0.5em` to `0.5em 1em` to adjust for the padding that was removed from the parent.

```js
Classes = ['number', 'black', 'circle'];
$('.td').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $span = $(this).children('span');
  var state = $span.data('state');
  $span.removeClass(Classes[state]);
  state = ++state % 3;
  console.log(state);
  $span.data('state', state).addClass(Classes[state]);
});
```

```css
* {
  font-size: 1em;
}
#game {
  display: table;
}
.tr {
  display: table-row;
}
.td {
  display: table-cell;
  margin: 1em;
  border: 1px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
.number,
.black,
.circle {
  padding: .5em 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: center;
  transition: ease 1s;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}
.black {
  color: white;
  background-color: rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.8);
}
.circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
span {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='game'>
  <div class='tr'>
    <div class='td'><span class='number' data-state='0'>4</span>

    </div>
    <div class='td'><span class='number' data-state='0'>5</span>

    </div>
    <div class='td'><span class='number' data-state='0'>1</span>

    </div>
    <div class='td'><span class='number' data-state='0'>2</span>

    </div>
    <div class='td'><span class='number' data-state='0'>4</span>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='tr'>
    <div class='td'><span class='number' data-state='0'>5</span>

    </div>
    <div class='td'><span class='number' data-state='0'>4</span>

    </div>
    <div class='td'><span class='number' data-state='0'>3</span>

    </div>
    <div class='td'><span class='number' data-state='0'>2</span>

    </div>
    <div class='td'><span class='number' data-state='0'>1</span>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='tr'>
    <div class='td'><span class='number' data-state='0'>3</span>

    </div>
    <div class='td'><span class='number' data-state='0'>3</span>

    </div>
    <div class='td'><span class='number' data-state='0'>2</span>

    </div>
    <div class='td'><span class='number' data-state='0'>1</span>

    </div>
    <div class='td'><span class='number' data-state='0'>4</span>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='tr'>
    <div class='td'><span class='number' data-state='0'>1</span>

    </div>
    <div class='td'><span class='number' data-state='0'>4</span>

    </div>
    <div class='td'><span class='number' data-state='0'>5</span>

    </div>
    <div class='td'><span class='number' data-state='0'>3</span>

    </div>
    <div class='td'><span class='number' data-state='0'>2</span>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='tr'>
    <div class='td'><span class='number' data-state='0'>5</span>

    </div>
    <div class='td'><span class='number' data-state='0'>1</span>

    </div>
    <div class='td'><span class='number' data-state='0'>2</span>

    </div>
    <div class='td'><span class='number' data-state='0'>4</span>

    </div>
    <div class='td'><span class='number' data-state='0'>4</span>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

In case you don't want the circle to touch the grid on all sides, make the following changes:

```css
.number, .black, .circle {
  margin: .1em;
  padding: .4em .9em;
}

.black {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 .1em black;
}
```

Comment: Excellent answer as always. I have added another option that I think fits better the last requirement of the OP.

Comment: Thanks @vals. I actually read/interpreted that point the other way (as in, OP wanted the circle to touch the grid on all sides instead of just 2 as in question). I will let your edit remain though just in case my interpretation was wrong :)