# Curved Button Outline CSS in HTML

Tags: css, html

I want to make outline around button. But as default instead of curved it is coming as a rectangle shape. Please guide me to make curved rounded outline using CSS.

Thanks

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
   <style> 
   input {
       border: 2px solid #a1a1a1;
       padding: 10px 40px; 
       background: #dddddd;
       width: 300px;
       border-radius: 25px;
       outline : 2px solid red;
   }
   </style>
   </head>
   <body>

          <input type="button" value="Button" />

   </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Outline radius?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5394116/outline-radius)

Answer (score 2):

You can try giving `box-shadow` instead of `outline`. Like:

```
input {
  border: 2px solid #a1a1a1;
  padding: 10px 40px; 
  background: #dddddd;
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px red;
}
```

Have a look at the snippet below:

```css
input {
   border: 2px solid #a1a1a1;
   padding: 10px 40px; 
   background: #dddddd;
   width: 300px;
   border-radius: 25px;
   box-shadow: 0 0 5px red;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <input type="button" value="Button" />
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: As per my Guideline instruction i should not use box-shadow. without box-shadow i should be do the outline.

Answer (score 1):

Natively this is not possible. Firefox has a property `-moz-outline-radius` but is not supported by all browsers.

You can check out this article for help with multiple borders, it has various techniques.

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/multiple-borders/

Answer (score 0):

try this instead, create a class called outline-button

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
   <style> 
   .outline-button {
       border: 2px solid #a1a1a1;
       padding: 10px 40px; 
       background: #dddddd;
       width: 300px;
       border-radius: 25px;
   }
   </style>
   </head>
   <body>

          <input class ="outline-button" type="button" value="Button" />

   </body>
   </html>
```

Answer (score -1):

`border-radius` will do the trick.

RE: It is because of the `outline` try to remove that line.

Comment: OP is using `border-radius` in the post!

Comment: Still not helpful. OP is asking how to style `outline` and you told them to remove it.