# How to remove outline on circular button when clicked

Tags: html, css

[image: ]]]]

How do I remove the blue border around my circular button when I click it.

Comment: button:focus{outline :none;}

Comment: @RachelGallen my apologies, did not know about the accepted answer feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this example I have changed the `border-color` from blue to `transparent` and added `outline:none;` on `:focus` (could also add not enabled)

Hope this helps

```css
button {width:50px;
height:50px;
background-image:url("http://www.rachelgallen.com/images/purpleflowers.jpg");
background-size:70% 70%;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:center center;
border-width:3px;
border-style: solid;
border-color:#000099;
}
button:focus{
 border-color:transparent!important;
 outline:none;
}
```

```html
<button>

</button>
```

Comment: Is there a way to make the outline circular with CSS?

Comment: @evolross your question has been asked a few times before. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11426967) and the other answers given to the corresponding question.

Answer (score 1):

Use `outline` Property :

```
selector {

 outline:none;

}
```

**Example :**

```css
.btn {

     outline: none;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">Click Me!</button>
```