# Rounded outline offset in html table

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I try to round each number in html tables,I apply `outline-offset`.

It seems the shape is not rounded.

Are there any method for round shape and rounded by `aqua`?

Thanks

```css
.color {
    background-color: rgb(0,255,0);
    border-radius: 10px;
    outline: 3px solid aqua;
    outline-offset: -3px;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td class=color>1</td>
<td class=color>2</td>
<td class=color>3</td>

</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Outline radius?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5394116/outline-radius)

Comment: I believe it's a Firefox only property. Add the `-moz-` prefix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot round the `outline`, but you can round the corners of the border inside.

The `table-cell` style does not allow all the styles that a typical `div` or `span` tag can have. Nest your cell data in another element and set styling on that.

```css
table {
  border: 3px solid orange;
}

td {
  padding: 0.25em;
}

.color {
  background-color: rgb(0, 255, 0);
  border-radius: 10px; /* around the border */
  border: 3px solid red; /* inside the outline, outside the padding */
  outline: 3px solid aqua; /* inside the cell, outside the offset/border */
  outline-offset: 3px; /* inside the outline, outside the border */
  padding: 0.25em; /* inside the border */
  margin: 3px; /* inside the cell, outside the outline */
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><div class="color">1</div></td>
    <td><div class="color">2</div></td>
    <td><div class="color">3</div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

For rounding each number please use the below code snippet.

```css
#rcorners1 {
  border-radius:85px;
  padding: 10px; 
  width: 20px;
  height: 15px;  
   background-color: rgb(0,255,0);
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td class=rcorners1 id=rcorners1>1</td>
<td class=rcorners1 id=rcorners1>2</td>
<td class=rcorners1 id=rcorners1>3</td>

</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Using duplicate ids is invalid html. It's also more conventional to always use quotes around attribute values.