# How to set radius for outline

Tags: html, css, sass, outline

I want to use border and outline on my element with some radius.

`border-radius` is only working for border.

Is there any way to apply radius on outline too?

```
.myElement {
    border: 2px solid #0064D2;
    outline: 2px solid #0099F8;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Outline radius?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5394116/outline-radius)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not currently, though I believe it's planned, but you can simulate it with a box-shadow instead.

```css
.myElement {
  border: 2px solid #0064D2;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #0099f8;
}
```

```html
<div class="myElement">
  Hello World
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

unfortunately there is no way to add outline radius, but you can have same result with box shadow.

```css
.myElement {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid #0064d2;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 0px 5px #c70707;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="myElement"></div>
</body>

</html>
```