# How to make outline offset radius

Tags: html, css

Im trying to draw a border with radius corner within an img but I cant do it using the propertly "outline-offset: -10px" because the corners aren't radius.

I was trying with an absolute div with these properties:

```html
<figure title="Ruleta en Vivo" class="container-juego"> 
 <a href="#" style="position: relative;">
    <div style="
    width: calc(100% - 20px);
    height: calc(100% - 20px);
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid #FBC64D;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 5000;
    right: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    border-radius: 3px;
"></div>
 <img src="https://d1131w2enq9v80.cloudfront.net/img/logos/evolution/destacados/imagen_destacada-ruleta-en-vivo01.jpg" class="imgdestacada lazy loading" data-was-processed="true" style="">
 </a>
</figure>
```

```css
div {
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  height: calc(100% - 20px);
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #FBC64D;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 5000;
  right: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

Is there any easier way than this?

Result would be this:
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfpsL.png)

Comment: I'd avoid using outline over border anyway because it has accessibility implications.  It would be helpful if you could provide your HTML for a [mcve].

Comment: Please do not show CSS code only, without the HTML it is supposed to apply to - that tells us rather little. Depending on the actual structure, this should probably work without explicitly calculating width and height, and without applying any translation either. (If you have a wrapper element around the image, of the same width & height as the image, and with `position:relative`, then you can simply absolutely position a sibling of the image using `20px` for top/bottom/left/right, and don't need to specify width & height at all.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could just add an `after` to the container, place it on top and give the size and properties you want:

```css
div {
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
}
div:after {
  content:'';
  border: 1px solid #FBC64D;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display:block;
  height:calc(100% - 20px);
  width:calc(100% - 20px);
  position:absolute;
  top:10px;
  left:10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
<img src="https://d1131w2enq9v80.cloudfront.net/img/logos/evolution/destacados/imagen_destacada-ruleta-en-vivo01.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Add the following code in css file.

```
img {
     outline: 1px solid #FBC64D;
     outline-offset: -10px;
}
```

[image: solved image]

Comment: That's missing the border-radius. (Which is why they said upfront already that using outline-offset won't work for them.)

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5394116/outline-radius

Comment: What for? None of the solutions there use `outline-offset`, as far as I can see.